# In bash -- storing method return value

Tags: bash, methods

I'm trying to store a value returned from a method like this: `var=$(methodName)`, but the program never enters the method... It's weird because I do the same thing a few lines earlier (alreadyExists-variable in code sample), and it works fine. I had to do this: `var='methodName'` to make the program enter the method.

It works, so why care? I'm probably making a mistake, and I need to know what it is and learn from it. Let me know if you need more info to answer the question. Thanks!

```
overwriteOrNot()
{
    echo DEBUG
    # This debug string does not print if method is called from "local overwrite=$(overwriteOrNot)"
    # but prints if method is called from "local overwrite='overwriteOrNot'"
    ...
}

local alreadyExists=$(studentNumberExists studentNumber)
if $alreadyExists ; then
    # local overwrite=$(overwriteOrNot)
    local overwrite='overwriteOrNot'
...
```

Comment: By "returned method value", do you mean the return value (`$?`), or the stdout (`DEBUG`)?

Comment: Also, if you want to check if it's a non-empty string, that would be `if [ -n "$alreadyExists" ]`, not `if $alreadyExists`.

Comment: Also, in the future, make sure your example code is *runnable*, and that you describe both the output you expect it to provide, and the output it actually provides.

Comment: Sorry, the method overwriteOrNot has two return statements: return 0, and return 1

Comment: If it has return statements, then you need to use `$?` to capture its exit value: `overwriteOrNot; overwrite=$?`, or directly branch on its state.

Comment: also, you have comments about the debug string getting printed vs captured -- is that part of your question in any way?

Comment: ...also, what leads you to believe that `local overwrite='overwriteOrNot'` invokes `overwriteOrNot` as a function? Again, you need to show your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `return`, then you need to either directly branch on its result:

```
if overwriteOrNot; then
  : "the function returned 0"
else
  : "the function returned something other than 0"
fi
```

...or store the value of `$?` immediately after running the function:

```
overwriteOrNot
local overwrite=$?
```

Note that `return` can only return a single-byte integer. If you need to pass content which doesn't fit that type, it needs to be either passed on stdout or in a global variable.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could use the method directly in the if-statement like that. I'll keep in mind to make my code runnable in the future!

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
local overwrite='overwriteOrNot'
```

assigns a string; it doesn't invoke a function. Instead:

```
local overwrite=$(overwriteOrNot)
```

You can check the return value from calling overwriteOrNot with the *$?* variable, or by checking its numeric return value directly in a conditional statement like:

```
if overwriteOrNot; then
    :
fi
```

If you assign to *overwrite*, you can also check its value with any valid test condition such as equality, regular expression match, or emptiness. For example:

```
if [[ "$overwrite" == "foo" ]]; then
    :
fi
```

Comment: Actually, `local overwrite='overwriteOrNot'` does invoke the method

Comment: @hatakeK It can't, because it's a string assignment. You are either using the wrong terminology, or not showing all of the relevant code. Your mileage will therefore vary.

Comment: I got it from here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions

Second code example says:
result=$(myfunc)   # or result=`myfunc`

Comment: @hatakeK, that's article's example is using backticks, your code example here used normal single quotes. Backticks trigger command substitution, single quotes do not. Backticks are these: `\``; your code in the question used these: `'`

Comment: I guess I didn't see that when I first tried using single quotes, but still -- it's working fine with single quotes. Couldn't find any documentation, but I guess the interpreter prioritizes executing the method (if it exists) over assigning the string